# Web application in Flask not stable on App Engine (work fine in local)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, gcloud, flask-session

This is my first web application "ChordMaster". It basically run a simple score editor and, at the end, you can print a pdf file. 
It works perfectly well in local using Flask, Flask Session, Javascript, SQLAlchmy ect... but when it's deployed on app engine (Google Cloud Platform), it seems that the return render_template() doesn't work properly : it doesn't pass the correct html page and/or values. As I'm using @login_required for every pages with Flask Session, something may get lost when the user POST, but can't figure out what's wrong. Greatly appreciate the help from you guys.

You can check out the app deployed: 
https://chordmaster-279503.ts.r.appspot.com/login

Here below is the beginning of the code that shows the first page "index":

Thanks a lot,

````
import os
import datetime
import requests
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, Sequence, asc, desc, update, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func

from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, InternalServerError
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from helpers import apology, login_required

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Connect to database
db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]
db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
cloud_sql_connection_name = os.environ["CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME"]

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername="mysql+pymysql",
        username=db_user, 
        password=db_pass,
        database=db_name, 
        query={
            "unix_socket": "{}/{}".format(
                db_socket_dir, 
                cloud_sql_connection_name) 
        }
    ),
)

# Defining metadata woth SQLAlchemy
metadata = MetaData()

# Ensure responses aren't cached
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

################ INDEX #################
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():

    # Reflecting metadata 
    metadata = MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True)
    song_list = metadata.tables["song_list"]
    song_modif = metadata.tables["song_modif"]

    # Go to the "Edit" menu to work on the selected song
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Set the time at the moment of the submission
        time = datetime.datetime.now()

        # Get the selected song from the user
        song_name = request.form.get("text")

        # Create a backlog table of all operations
        with engine.connect() as conn:

            # Insert new modif
            ins = song_modif.insert().values(user_id=session["user_id"], song_name=song_name, time=time)
            conn.execute(ins)

            # Select all the current chord/bar from the updated table
            s = song_modif.select().where(song_modif.c.user_id==session["user_id"]).order_by(song_modif.c.time.desc())
            song_name_list = conn.execute(s).fetchall()

            # Get the name of the current song
            song_name=song_name_list[0]['song_name']

            # Select all the current chord/bar from the updated table
            song_table = metadata.tables[song_name]
            sc = song_table.select().order_by(song_table.c.bar.asc())
            song_complete = conn.execute(sc).fetchall()

            # Create format arguments for the table in html
            new_line_dict = conn.execute(select([func.count(song_table.c.bar)])).fetchone()

        # Create format arguments for the table in html
        new_line = int(new_line_dict[0]) / 4

        return render_template("tabreader.html", song_name=song_name, song_complete=song_complete, new_line=new_line)
    else:
        # Return the list of song
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            s = song_list.select().where(song_list.c.user_id==session["user_id"]).order_by(song_list.c.time.desc())
            list_of_song = conn.execute(s).fetchall()

        return render_template("index.html", song_list=list_of_song)

    return render_template("index.html")
```
````

Comment: Without stack trace, it's very difficult to help you. render_template works properly, your code may not. What I am thinking would be that: when you deployed, you change the domain name (from localhost to your new one). Maybe you have hardcoded some hyperlinks and try to reach localhost. If you do not have the correct value from the DB. maybe you cannot access your DB and then it returns always None. It could be a lot of things. But mostly hardcoded links, wrong connector the the DB, wrong paths, etc...Hope you find a solution or give us more detail about your error.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `render_template()` function is searching for a folder called `templates` (case sensitive). Within the `templates` folder is where your index.html (and all of your other HTML files) should be located.

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/api/) for python flask's Flask() function, the default `templates` folder can be renamed when instantiating your Flask application at the very top of your main flask engine file. For example, if you don't want a `templates` folder, then you can rename it to something else, such as 'folder_that_has_html_files'

`app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='folder_that_has_html_files')`